# How do I get the inner react-text of an element using Selenium WebDriver and Java?

Tags: reactjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I am testing an application which contains a lot of dynamic data. I am trying to access the inner text of the last element within a group of messages. The HTML is:

```
<div class="MessageList">
   <li>
      <div class="Message-mine">
          <div class=Message-block">
          <div>
              <div class="Message-text">
              <!-- react-text:1200 -->
              Hey there!
              <!-- /react-text -->
          </div>
          ….
          </div>
       </div>
   </li>
   <li>
      <div class="Message-mine">
          <div class=Message-block">
          <div>
              <div class="Message-text">
              <!-- react-text:1201 -->
              Hey there again!
              <!-- /react-text -->
          </div>
          ….
          </div>
       </div>
   </li>
   ….
</div>
```

I would like to verify that the last 'Message-mine' block contains the text "Hey there again!". I am using Selenium Webdriver and Java.

I have tried the following:

In my Page Object(Messages):

```
@FindBy(xpath="//div[@class='Message-text']")
public WebElement messageTextBox;
```

In my test cases:

```
AssertEquals(messages.messageTextBox.getText(), "Hey there!");
```

(I ultimately want to be able to retrieve the last message. But above, I simply wanted to verify the first.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rule is, if the following:

```
@FindBy(xpath="//div[@class='Message-text']")
public WebElement messageTextBox;
```

has more than one match, then return the **first one**. Which sounds like the opposite of what you want.

You probably want:

```
@FindBy(className="Message-text")
public List<WebElement> messageTextBoxes;
```

which will give you all of them. To get the last one now, you will need:

```
WebElement lastMessageTextBox = messageTextBoxes.get(messageTextBoxes.size() - 1);
AssertEquals(lastMessageTextBox.getText(), "Hey there!");
```

Comment: Thank you! However, my test fails at  WebElement lastMessageTextBox = messageTextBoxes.get(messageTextBoxes.size() - 1); I get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1 ….so I figure it isn't locating any of the message text boxes, and I'm not sure why.

Comment: if you are getting list of webelements in POM it should be like this `@FindBys(@FindBy(className="Message-text"))` `public List<WebElement> messageTextBoxes;`

Comment: I actually needed a sleep! Took a little longer for those to render. Thanks for your help!!!!

Comment: @Pratik That is **not** correct! See: https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/FindBy.html and  https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/FindBys.html

Comment: Oh okay. Lack of information. Thank you for letting me know.

Comment: @Pratik FYI: there is also a similar `@FindAll` https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/FindAll.html